# Does the Google Maps iOS SDK function properly in China?

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

If so, do we need to whitelist any servers for HTTP (not HTTPS) data transfer? If not, is there a recommended fallback?

Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#china_ws_access